# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find network parameters file and compatibility zone wasn't configured/isn't reachable

Tags: corda

After run this command **java -jar network-bootstrapper-4.1.jar --dir**  it could generate the network parameter file.but it doesn't generate the network parameter file

And i attached the node.conf file.

```
 myLegalName="O=Notary,L=Mumbai,C=IN"
        notary {
            validating=true
        }
        p2pAddress="localhost:9006"
        rpcUsers=[]
        devMode : true
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't have more context around the question to determine how to solve your problem here, but I will say that in the latest version of corda; generally when running the bootstrapper you'll want to pass a directory of nodes.

java -jar network-bootstrapper-4.4.jar --dir

Each of the files in that folder should have a node.conf file that is unique so that the bootstrapper can generate the correct files.

However there are newer tools for running corda nodes / networks more easily. if you take a look at some of the developer samples they now provide gradle tasks for you to build and run your corda nodes.

link to other corda sample apps : https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Basic/yo-cordapp

source docs: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/network-bootstrapper.html